# dragover event, target needs to be element with draggable

Tags: javascript

I need to get the parent element which has got the `draggable` attribute assigned to it, as this also has some other data attributes I need.

However if I click and drag on a child element of course this is the target.

Is there a way to do this without a horrid `findAncestor` loop?

```html
  <div class="panel" draggable="true" data-move-id="1">
        <div data-move-handle class="panel-heading"></div>
        <div class="panel-block"></div>
        <div class="panel-block"></div>
        <div class="panel-block"></div>
        <div class="panel-block"></div>
    </div>
```

Or, better yet, is there a way I can limit the draggable handle to the div with the `data-move-handle` attribute, however I still want the entire div to move. Then I can move the `data-move-id` to that div.

Comment: What have you tried so far? We can't write code for you, but we can help you debug what you've written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have data available when you drop, from your 'dragged' element, you have to include it in your event. This can get tricky with cross browser implementations, especially if you have to support legacy (i.e. IE) browsers.

```
const startDrag(event) {
  // 'this' is the 'draggable' you are attaching this method to,
  // so if you need the data attribute just use this.getAttribute()
  // get it.
  // get the data you need to transfer with your object, and then
  event.dataTransfer.setData('text', JSON.stringify(somesetofdata));
}

const drop(event) {
  let data = event.dataTransfer.getData('text');
  data = data ? JSON.parse(data) : data;
  // do something with it
}
```

That's sorta the gist. Google 'Pure Javascript Drag and Drop' for a lot of example code. Here's a [really simple example](https://medium.com/quick-code/simple-javascript-drag-drop-d044d8c5bed5).